# Context Variable from txt file

Tags: talend

I am trying to get Context (data connection) variable (Database input) from Txt file. This is the input of my txt file.

host;"xxx"
port;"xxx"
database;"xxx"
username;"xxx"
password;"xY"
database;"xx"
schema;"xY"

This is the query I am using to get table information "SELECT * FROM COMPANY". I have tried with Database. Table name also. But I am getting below error. "Exception in component tDBInput_1 (DataConnection_FromFile)

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Invalid number format for port number"

Could you please suggest do I need to follow any other steps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your port number context variable is typed as 'Integer'. Try to modify this and put it as a String in the 'Context' view.